# Why can't I view branches remotely

Tags: git

I have a repository set up on a server running Git, the repository has an authoritive / bare repository connected to it. If I then set up a local version of the repository on my development machine with:

```
git clone //ip-address/projectfolder/project.git
```

I can view all of the code without any problems.

However, when I create a branch on the Git server with `git checkout -b v1_0_2_1` I can't see the new branch on my development machine. I've tried running `git remote update`
and when I type `git branch -a` I can only see:

```
* master
  remote/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Something's wrong here: `//ip-address/projectfolder/project.git` indicates a **bare** repo (implicit because of the `.git` extension) where you cannot create a branch....

Comment: Well spotted @eckes, +1. Peter's suggestion didn't initially work for me but that was because I'd messed up the setup of the intial project. It works fine now I've set it up properly in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
git fetch origin
```

This will get all branches from the remote repo and store them under remotes/origin/*branchname*

example :

```
ptimac:pfus pti$ git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 2283, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (892/892), done.
remote: Total 2009 (delta 990), reused 1698 (delta 688)
Receiving objects: 100% (2009/2009), 297.21 KiB | 256 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (990/990), completed with 152 local objects.
From github.com:melexis/pfus
   d989914..c09b843  PFUS-682   -> origin/PFUS-682
 * [new branch]      PFUS-686   -> origin/PFUS-686
   b3d0fd2..33e5dd6  PFUS-688   -> origin/PFUS-688
   9765ff2..afe0103  PFUS-697   -> origin/PFUS-697
 * [new branch]      PFUS-699   -> origin/PFUS-699
 * [new branch]      PFUS-700   -> origin/PFUS-700
 * [new branch]      PFUS-768   -> origin/PFUS-768
 * [new branch]      PFUS-769   -> origin/PFUS-769
 * [new branch]      PFUS-770   -> origin/PFUS-770
 * [new branch]      PFUS-771   -> origin/PFUS-771
 * [new branch]      PFUS-773   -> origin/PFUS-773
 * [new branch]      UAT-PATCH  -> origin/UAT-PATCH
   004d135..bc210a6  master     -> origin/master
```

Here I got the new work from my team mates, each works on their own branch, which corresponds to a ticket.

```
ptimac:pfus pti$ git branch -a 
  PROD
* UAT
  UAT_V1
  master
  remotes/origin/AUDIT
  remotes/origin/CUKES
  remotes/origin/CUKES_RUBY
  remotes/origin/FIX_AUDIT
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/INKLESS-423
... many lines snipped ...
```

And here are the branches in the local repo.